# ComboBox fires change event on every keypress

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm trying to build grid with combobox in toolbar, in Grid I will have some informations about employees and combo will allow me to select employee I would like to load those info.

I've created grid easily, but I have problem with combobox in toolbar: it fires change event every time I type something.

```
Ext.define('My.Grid.Combo', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    alias: 'widget.combostates',
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    forceSelection: true,
    listeners: {
        change: function (field, newValue, oldValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
        },
        scope: this
    }
});
```

Here is my demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Misiu/LTVXF/

Put cursor inside that combo and start typing. After every key press that event is fired (see console)

I would like to get that event (or other, doesn't matter) to fire after user selects valid element from that checkbox (I'm using forceSelection).
I could add `editable: false,` but I would like to have local filtering after I enter part of valid value.

Comment: Can you not use the `select` event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because it actually is changing the value every time you hit a key. What you want to use is the `select` listener. Using this you can grab the value out of the record that was selected.

```
listeners: {
    select: function(combo, records, eOpts) {
        console.log(records[0].get('name'));
        console.log(records[0].get('abbr'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I just found in ExtJS documentation that event. Thanks for such fast answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "scope: this". Once you remove it, when you call this in the event you will be able to see the combobox from which the event is fired. Otherwise it will be the value of window.